# Is there a way I can track a class change of a website source code on real time?

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension, that must trigger a process if a specific class on a website source has changed. Is there a way of doing that on real time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect changes in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the MutationObserver interface as shown in [Gabriele Romanato's blog](https://gabrieleromanato.name/jquery-detecting-new-elements-with-the-mutationobserver-object)

Chrome 18+, Firefox 14+, IE 11+, Safari 6+

```js
// The node to be monitored
var target = $( "#content" )[0];

// Create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function( mutations ) {
  mutations.forEach(function( mutation ) {
    var newNodes = mutation.addedNodes; // DOM NodeList
    if( newNodes !== null ) { // If there are new nodes added
        var $nodes = $( newNodes ); // jQuery set
        $nodes.each(function() {
            var $node = $( this );
            if( $node.hasClass( "message" ) ) {
                // do something
            }
        });
    }
  });    
});

// Configuration of the observer:
var config = { 
    attributes: true, 
    childList: true, 
    characterData: true 
};

// Pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

// Later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```